# Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android

my activity is continuously crashing, this just shows only text on UI, please tell me what I am doing wrong.This is showing error in XML file but according to me the XML file is fine, I am not able to find the bug in XML file.
Here is my code

```
public class PlacedOrderConfirmation extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.place_order_confirmation);
    TextView placed_successful_txt=    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.placed_successful_txt);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String edit_order_id = intent.getStringExtra("EDIT_OR_PLACE") != null ? intent.getStringExtra("EDIT_OR_PLACE") : "";
    if(edit_order_id!=null && edit_order_id.length()>0){
        placed_successful_txt.setText("YOUR ORDER HAS BEEN\nUPDATED SUCCESSFULLY");
    }
    Button notification_icon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notification_icon);
    ImageView btnContinue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cont);
    notification_icon.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (Utility.getDeviceHeight(this) * .04);
    notification_icon.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (Utility.getDeviceHeight(this) * .04);
    btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PlacedOrderConfirmation.this, ContractorDashboard.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_summary"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding="10dp">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/confirmation"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notification_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/congratulation"
    android:textSize="42sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/placed_successful_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/orderplaced"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/emailsent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/gray_base"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="@string/click"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    />





<ImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/cont"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/forward_arrow"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the logcat

```
10-20 10:48:08.394 24918-24918/com.loadarmy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.loadarmy, PID: 24918
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.loadarmy/com.loadarmy.contractor.PlacedOrderConfirmation}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #89: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #89: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:672)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1940)
at com.loadarmy.contractor.PlacedOrderConfirmation.onCreate(PlacedOrderConfirmation.java:19)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:672) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1940) 
at com.loadarmy.contractor.PlacedOrderConfirmation.onCreate(PlacedOrderConfirmation.java:19) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:601)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:434)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2503)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2155)
at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2062)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3558)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:672) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1940) 
at com.loadarmy.contractor.PlacedOrderConfirmation.onCreate(PlacedOrderConfirmation.java:19) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: notification_icon.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (Utility.getDeviceHeight(this) * .04);
    notification_icon.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (Utility.getDeviceHeight(this) * .04); comment these 2 lines and check

Comment: these lines defining the size of icon according to device height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set background images to your LinearLayout and Button of your xml. one of those images are giving `OutOfMemoryError` try reducing size of your image or change it.

Comment: Size of forward arrow is 27Kb only another one is 57 Kb

Comment: Have you tried android:largeHeap="true" in application tag of your menifest ?

Comment: dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }  Allready added in gradle file

Comment: please try changing it with  javaMaxHeapSize "4g" and put that android:largeHeap="true" in your menifest.

Comment: By enabling android:largeHeap="true" in manifest my code is working fine. Thanks @Mayank Pandya

Answer (score 1):

You are getting **[OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)**

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because
>   it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the
>   garbage collector.

This error showing when the application attempts to add more data into the heap space area, but there is not enough room for it.

Reduce **Image Resolution** at first and set `android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest .