# android.view.InflateException with android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os, action-drawer

I'm using the example in this [Android Developers Document](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/ui-nav-actions.html) to try to implement an "Action Drawer". The project compiles, but upon loading, it immediately crashes. The sample app runs, and I've tried to copy all the relevant parts almost verbatim. **Can anybody explain why it can't instantiate/inflate the class?**

Error messages on xml layout file:

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawer
>
> The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout

Stack trace:

> 08-05 15:57:46.287 3993-3993/com.mendonphoto.abeddes.run2gps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.mendonphoto.abeddes.run2gps, PID: 3993
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mendonphoto.abeddes.run2gps/com.mendonphoto.run2gps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #301: Binary XML file line #301: Error inflating class android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawer
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #301: Binary XML file line #301: Error inflating class android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawer
>                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #301: Error inflating class android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawer
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
>                                                                                      at com.mendonphoto.run2gps.MainActivity.setLayout(MainActivity.java:646)
>                                                                                      at com.mendonphoto.run2gps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:680)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6682)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>                                                                                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
>                                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:770)
>                                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:742)
>                                                                                      at android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawerMenu$WearableActionDrawerMenuItem.setIcon(WearableActionDrawerMenu.java:268)
>                                                                                      at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:441)
>                                                                                      at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:494)
>                                                                                      at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:190)
>                                                                                      at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:111)
>                                                                                      at android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawer.(WearableActionDrawer.java:163)
>   08-05 15:57:46.288 3993-3993/com.mendonphoto.abeddes.run2gps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawer.(WearableActionDrawer.java:106)
>                                                                                      at android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawer.(WearableActionDrawer.java:102)
>                                                                                       ... 26 more

Here's the layout in my xml file:

```
<android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mendonphoto.run2gps.MainActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear">

...a bunch of stuff

</android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout>
```

And my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mendonphoto.abeddes.run2gps"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
```

Comment: added in version 26.0.0-beta2

Comment: The example project uses version 25. Its build.gradle contains:
"android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"..."
I'm confused...

Comment: I tried to simulate on a device running 26, and it fails the same way.

Comment: This error might happen if you set background images to your LinearLayout and Button of your xml because one of those images are giving [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html). From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40146171/5832311), try reducing size of your image or change it. Here's another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719620/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-trouble-in-android) for additional information.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using AndroidX, this import should be:

```
androidx.wear:wear:[version]
```

And the XML should reference the following fully qualified path:

```
<androidx.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout …
```

See also [the AndroidX migration guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was missing the "android:icon" flags in the drawer menu xml file. Apparently, icons are required for an action drawer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and now solved it.
I think you should use `com.android.support:wear`.

Like this

```
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.5'
compile 'com.android.support:wear:26.1.0'
```

Read this document.
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/wear-ui-library.html